# How to add/override properties in interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface `A` and need to create type that extends `A`, but overrides definition of property `type`

```js
interface A {
    type: 'user';
    name: string;
}

type B = ???

let q: B = {
    type: 'admin',
    name: 'John'
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Omit` in an intersection with another type that adds the property back with a different type:

```
type B = Omit<A, 'type'> & {
  type: "admin"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-JgCeADhAFzIDkArgM7RUDcuByIcAthcnWFKADmLHAF9cuYmWQAhZAF5kAeU7AwAHlQAaalIhUAfMgBkmVoVI8ARHAAmqkFdzicuADYQwyAI6U5i7DwCPUoqOwcqLXN8Dm5QgCkAewALECpnIA)

You can also create a more general version of this replace type:

```
type Replace<T, TOverride> = Omit<T, keyof TOverride> & TOverride

type B =  Replace<A,  {
  type: "admin"
}>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-JgCeADhAFzIDkArgM7RUDcuByIcAthcnWFKADmLHAF9cuYmWQAlCCQA2iCAB4AKgBpkagPIA3aAIAmEAHzIAvMh2dgYdVoDWEIgHsY2-YeAnzAMk8DKGMICRwpFAAhS3w5RWUVVC1MVkJSHgAiOCNbEAzcUVMwhQgwZABHSmirbDwCCMoqbNyqDVT8Dm5GgClXAAsQKgKgA)

Answer (score 1):

```
type B = Omit<A, 'type'> & {type: 'admin'};
```